# Multiple usb-devices in device-filter.xml

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-studio

I was wondering if it's possible to have multiple usb-devices in the device-filter.xml file. I have different product-id's for each usb-device. Although I can do this in my code like this:

```
if (dev.value.vendorId == 1111 && dev.value.productId == 24444 || dev.value.productId == 24445)
```

The device-filter makes it able when connecting the usb-device to create a checkbox that will always connect to it, so that it won't show a popup everytime it connects with the usb-device.

Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="1111" product-id="24444" />
</resources>
```

I tried adding a second <usb device"> to it but this doesn't work. Anything I can try that will make this work? Thanks

Edit:
It looks like you can do this:

```
<usb-device vendor-id="1111" product-id="24444,24445" />
```